# Hashmap.put in streams/lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8, hashmap, iterator, java-stream

How do I Convert below Java code to Java 8 stream/lambda

my code written in < java 8

```
Map<Integer,Integer> mapss = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        mapss.put(new Integer(i),new Integer(i));
    }
    Iterator<Integer> integerIterator = mapss.keySet().iterator();
    while (integerIterator.hasNext()){
        Integer integer = integerIterator.next();
        System.out.println(integer+" Some "+mapss.get(integer));
    }
 //Car.java has attribute **private String data** 
  Map<Integer, Car> mapss = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        mapss.put(new Integer(i),new Car("Sample "));
    }
    Iterator<Integer> integerIterator = mapss.keySet().iterator();
    while (integerIterator.hasNext()){
        Integer integer = integerIterator.next();
        System.out.println(integer+" Some "+mapss.get(integer));
    }
```

Could you please some one help me transform above code to Java 8

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " Some " + value));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out replacing traditional **for loops** with **[IntStream](https://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-19-java-8-replace-traditional-for-loops-with-intstreams/)** and **rangeClosed**

**In your first case**

```
Map<Integer,Integer> mapss = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,5)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, Integer::intValue));
mapss.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println((key + " Some "+ value)));
```

**In your second case**

```
Map<Integer,Car> mapss = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,5)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, i -> new Car("Sample")));
mapss.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println((key + " Some "+ value)));
```